# A doubt in proof of path connected implies connected

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $X$ be a path-connected topological space and assume for a contradiction that $X=A \cup B$, where $A \cap B = \emptyset$ and $A,B \neq \emptyset$ (i.e. $X$ isn't connected). Choose $a \in A$, $b \in B$
Let $f: [0,1] \rightarrow X$
be a path in $X$ such that $f(0)=a$, $f(1)=b$. Then by continuity of $f$ there is a decomposition $$[0,1]=f^{-1}(A) \cup f^{-1}(B)$$ and this decomposition implies that $[0,1]$ is not connected, which is not true. Hence we conclude that $X$ cannot be path-connected, if it isn't connected.

I am studying Real analysis and don't really understand everything in topology. I will write all the troubles that I am having.

1) When we say that inverse image of an set, Is it necessary that all points in the set has to have inverse ? (In this case we took inverse of A where all points in A did not have its inverse.

2) So If 1) is true , then I am having trouble in understanding this theorem that if f is continuous function then inverse image of any open set is open set.

If f is a continuous function from [0,1] to [1,2] , Now If I take inverse image of (0,3) it should be an open set since it is inverse image of an open set under continuous function .But inverse image in this case is [0,1] which is closed .

So what is that I am missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) The inverse image of a set $A\subset Y$ under a map $f:X\to Y$ is the set of all elements of $X$ that $f$ sends to $A$. So:

$$f^{-1}(A)=\{x\in X: f(x)\in A\}$$

2) This is not a theorem -- it is the **definition** of a continuous function. A function $f:X\to Y$ is continuous (by definition) if the inverse image of every open set in $Y$ under $f$ is open in $X$.

3) In your final example, you have take care with the topology of $(0,3)$. It is not open in the range of $f$.

Comment: It might be treated as definition in topology but in real analysis delta -epsilon definition is used.

Comment: That's why it is best to study topology first :) Anyway, epsilon-delta is used when there are metrics around, and metrics of course induce topologies, and then it is very easy to see that the two definitions are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

The notation $f^{-1}(A)$ means the values $y\in [0,1]$ so that $f(y)\in A$.  It doesn't imply that every point $c\in A$ has an inverse... i.e. some $y\in [0,1]$ so that $f(y)=c$.

As to the second question, the interval $[0,1]$ is an open set if that is the whole space.  I.e. $[0,1]$ is an open set in $[0,1]$, but $[0,1]$ is not an open set in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Okay .I understood the mistake .